# What are the best methods to analyze the results of a pairwise comparison survey?

Tags: data-analysis, mathematics

I have recently conducted as survey where I was comparing a range of different images. Due to screen size constraints I decided to display these images pairwise and ask the participants to pick one of the images.

There were 4 images being compared and therefore 6 possible pair combinations. My data now looks something like this.

1. A vs. B - 6 chose A, 3 chose B
2. A vs. C - 2 chose A, 6 chose C
3. A vs. D - 8 chose A, 1 chose D
4. B vs. C - 2 chose B, 7 chose C
5. B vs. D - 6 chose B, 3 chose D
6. C vs. D - 8 chose C, 1 chose D

How do I determine which option is the favourite? Can I make claims such as A is preffered by 60% of participants etc?